# Microsoft responses after Purchased Product receipt verification

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

Guys I'm working on WP8 app and I've to verify the receipt of Microsoft after purchasing of app products. I want to know that what Microsoft server returns as response on verification or after verification of the receipt on Microsoft server.

Response could be anything an error or successfully verified? Please suggest some links where I can find out.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards

Amit Singh

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetAppReceiptAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx) method to query already purchased IAP receipts. In that link, at end there are some details about how to verify the receipt authenticity.

As part of purchase call, [RequestProductPurchaseAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh967814.aspx) does returns receipt contents if used includeReceipt variable in the method call.

Comment: Sorry sir, I think you didn't studied the suggested link  [GetAppReceiptAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx). You can see this line `Windows Phone 8
This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called.`. Still thanks a lot for the help, it will help me in future.

Comment: I missed that portion about not availability for WP8. Anyways you can try this sample http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/In-app-purchase-receipt-c3e0bce4